# error at lua script: attempt to index a nil value (local 'f') when running cheat engine

Tags: lua, cheat-engine

I'm getting this error at this point in the code...
But I don't think there's something wrong...

```
function readAll(file)
  local f = io.open(file, "rb")
  local content = f:read("*all"); f:close()
  return content
end
```

I get this error **attempt to index a nil value (local 'f')** in this specific line:

```
local content = f:read("*all"); f:close()
```

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

I just tried to execute the script, but I got this error...
It was supposed to work without any errors...

I already tried to look around the internet, but nothing seems to be wrong with the code...

Comment: file just doesn't exist

Comment: how do i fix it?

Comment: try `io.open(file, "ab+")` to create a file  if it is missing

Comment: nothing helped you?

Answer (score 0):

first solution:

```
function readAll(file)
  local f = io.open(file, "ab+") -- create if it not exist
  local content = f:read("*all"); f:close()
  return content
end
```

second solution:

```
function readAll(file)
  local f = io.open(file, "rb+")
  if not f then return "" end -- check file
  local content = f:read("*all"); f:close()
  return content
end
```